# How to pass a go pointer as wasm context data?

Tags: go, webassembly

I'm looking at wasmer go-ext-wasm example code `/go-ext-wasm/wasmer/test/imports.go` learning about setting context data. I want to pass a pointer as contextData, what's the best way to do this?

```
//export sum
func sum(context unsafe.Pointer, x int32, y int32) int32 {
    instanceContext := wasm.IntoInstanceContext(context)
    t := *(*int)(instanceContext.Data())
    log.Print("t: ", t)
    return x + y
}

func testInstanceImport(t *testing.T) {
    imports, err := wasm.NewImports().Namespace("env").Append("sum", sum, C.sum)
    assert.NoError(t, err)

    instance, err := wasm.NewInstanceWithImports(getImportedFunctionBytes("examples", "imported_function.wasm"), imports)
    defer instance.Close()
    assert.NoError(t, err)

    bar := int(2)
    barPtr := &bar

    data := unsafe.Pointer(&bar)
    instance.SetContextData(data)
    log.Printf("bar %v, barPtr %v", bar, barPtr)
    add1, exists := instance.Exports["add1"]
    assert.Equal(t, true, exists)

    result, err := add1(1, 2)
    log.Print("Result: ", result)
    assert.Equal(t, wasm.I32(4), result)
    assert.NoError(t, err)
}
```

Which gives me the expected value of 2 for context in the sum function.  However when I change `data := unsafe.Pointer(&bar)` to `data := unsafe.Pointer(&barPtr)`  I get a: `runtime error: cgo argument has Go pointer to Go pointer` error.

It works when I run it with `GODEBUG=cgocheck=0`  Should I be concerned running with this flag?  Is what I'm trying to do a bad idea?  I have a struct that contains a pointer that I need to pass as contextData, is using the `GODEBUG=cgocheck=0` a bad idea?